# install ssl on lightsail without using load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-lightsail

Hey I am using aws Lightsail for deploying my nextjs container
I wanna install ssl on the lightsail instance
Can I do this without uing loadbalancer

please help me with some resources that I can follow and achieve my goal

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) SSL certs for this.

For eg:

You install Nginx on your instance and do a proxy pass to the container

```
upstream nextjs {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}


server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  isten [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass        http://nextjs;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
  }
}
```

Before restarting Nginx, install the letsencrypt ssl

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt

cd /opt/letsencrypt

sudo -H ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

For more info you can check this [page](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/ssl/install-lets-encrypt-to-create-ssl-certificates/)